# vb.net substring from end or third char

Tags: vb.net, string, substring

I have string 12|aaa|bbb|ccc|34 and I need to get ccc and then to replace it with some other value. 
So for example I have "`12..|aaa|bbb|ccc|34..`" and I need to get "`12..|aaa|bbb|" & getValOf(ccc) & "|34..`"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to use [`String.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), for example:

```
Dim text As String = "12|aaa|bbb|ccc|34"
text = text.Replace("ccc", "new string")
```

Note that i'm assigning the string that is returned from `String.Replace` to the orginal string. Otherwise it would not change since strings are immutable. So this does not work (if that was your original problem):

```
text.Replace("ccc", "new string") ' this string is not used at all
```

If you instead want to split the string by the pipe `|` and replace the fourth token(`ccc` in this case) with a different string, use `String.Split` and `String.Join`:

```
Dim tokens = text.Split("|"c)
tokens(3) = "new string"
text = String.Join("|", tokens)
```